# I keep getting WCF service is in faulted state on the client side. How should I catch WCF exceptions, without breaking my WCF service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have a WCF service multiple UIs consume.   When the user is unable to access the database, I get Unauthorised exception from the DB. I don't catch the exception on the server side and send it to the client.

On the client (asp.net webpage), I get to see the exception - User was unable to access the database, login failed.  **This is all good.** But... if I make a call to the WCF service again, I get the exception that the service is in faulted state.  Only open is to restart the entire WCF service. WCF service is hosted as a windows service.

**What is the best way to catch the exceptions, log the exception on server side, send the exception details back to the client without breaking the service?  Thanks**

Comment: try using faultcontract.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unhandled exceptions will fault the communication channel.  As others have pointed out, a faulted channel must be aborted by calling `Abort()` - it can't be closed and it can't be used again.

To address the other part of your question, the "best way to catch the exceptions, log the exception on server side, send the exception details back to the client without breaking the service?", you need to use [FaultException Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.faultexception.aspx).

Additionally, you can use the [IErrorHandler Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx) to wire up your service host to catch any exceptions that were not otherwise caught (i.e., a global error handler).  There are many examples of how to do this on the net - just google for WCF IErrorHandler.

Here's a couple:

[WCF Exception Handling with IErrorHandler](http://blog.wadolabs.com/2009/03/wcf-exception-handling-with-ierrorhandler/)

[WCF Extensibility – IErrorHandler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/07/wcf-extensibility-ierrorhandler.aspx)

Comment: thanks. when should i catch the exceptions and throw fault exceptions? in operation contracts or in windows service onstart code which creates service host objects?

Comment: You'd catch the exception in the service, serialize it as a fault contract, and then the client (or the windows service) can catch the fault exception in a try-catch block.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code to create a wrapper class that will properly handle WCF exceptions:

```
public class ServiceProxyHelper<TProxy, TChannel> : IDisposable
    where TProxy : ClientBase<TChannel>, new()
    where TChannel : class
{
    ///
    /// Private instance of the WCF service proxy.
    ///
    private TProxy _proxy;

    ///
    /// Gets the WCF service proxy wrapped by this instance.
    ///
    public TProxy Proxy
    {
        get
        {
            if (_proxy != null)
            {
                return _proxy;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ObjectDisposedException("ServiceProxyHelper");
            }
        }
    }

    public TChannel Channel { get; private set; }

    ///
    /// Constructs an instance.
    ///
    public ServiceProxyHelper()
    {
        _proxy = new TProxy();
    }

    ///
    /// Disposes of this instance.
    ///
    public void Dispose()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_proxy != null)
            {
                if (_proxy.State != CommunicationState.Faulted)
                {
                    _proxy.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    _proxy.Abort();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (CommunicationException)
        {
            _proxy.Abort();
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
            _proxy.Abort();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            _proxy.Abort();
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            _proxy = null;
        }
    }
}
```

You can then call a service like this:

```
using (ServiceProxyHelper<EmailServiceClient, EmailService> svc =
   new ServiceProxyHelper<EmailServiceClient, EmailService>())
{
   svc.Proxy.SendMail(fromAddress, fromName, toEmail, toName, message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the following link which talks about how WCF clients should catch faults/exceptions and potential problems you may run into with the 'using' statement in C#:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx

Baiscally you need to call Abort() on your client proxy.  This will immediately set the state of the proxy to Closed.

Comment: oh great. do you think it is ok to throw exceptions back to the client from wcf service?

Comment: I think that really depends on the type of application you're building and what your overall exception handling strategy is.  That being said, if this is an end user facing application, you probably want to let them know something went wrong.