# Manually produce System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject Faulted event

Tags: c#, wcf, wcfserviceclient

I have WCF service that sometimes rise `Faulted` event on production for yet unknown reasons.
I want to reproduce and test such situation in development environment, but I don't understand how to achieve that.

`Faulted` event belongs to `System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject` and inherit by `System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost` that I use to host my WCF service.

I there any way to force my `ServiceHost` produce `Faulted` event? I tried to manually corrupt client side wcf contract, but it just failed on client side due contract mismatch and service still works properly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The Failed state does not exist. But, if you are talking about a generic way to close the host you can try:

```
System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.Host.Close();
```

If a failure is mandatory for you, than the state you're looking for is Faulted. The Host object (whose type is System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject) has a method named [Fault()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.communicationobject.fault?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0), which isn't public, but you'll probably be able to call it with a bit of reflection. That should make the Host transitioning into the Faulted state.

You can also use a host derived from WebServiceHost:

```
class MyWebServiceHost : System.ServiceModel.Web.WebServiceHost
{
    public MyWebServiceHost(Type serviceType, params Uri[] baseAddresses)
    : base (serviceType, baseAddresses)
    {

    }

    public void Fail()
    {
        base.Fault();
    }
}
```

source:[Force WCF Host into Faulted State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29906271/force-wcf-host-into-faulted-state)